# okHttp fails with retrofit while using vpn

Tags: retrofit2, vpn, okhttp

I've been using my code on my company networks and it works really fine, but when I want to use it from my home (using a vpn to connect to the company network), it fails saying :
Unable to resolve host X: No adress associated with hostname.

What is weird is that I actually can use the link in the browser (it works fine).
Is there any configuration that I need to add?

```
            OkHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request authorisedRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                .addHeader("Authorization", TNConstants.BASIC +
                                        Base64.encodeToString((username+ ":" + password).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP)).build();
                        return chain.proceed(authorisedRequest);
                    }}).build();
```

It actually fails in the chain.proceed(authorisedRequest) function.
Please help me with that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `okHttpClient.connectionPool.evictAll()` before your request call that may resolve your issue